# How could I avoid all this repetition with enumerated-like properties?

Tags: c#, dry

I have just found an insidious error caused by index mismatching inside my class, and this was due to code being repetitive and sequence-like.

My question: would there be another, more sensible way to expose properties (being used with WPF for databinding) without all this horrid repetition?

Code (with comments on worst parts):

```
public class MemoryTable
{

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    int TableNumber { get; set; }
    DeviceWrapper _device;

    public MemoryTable(DeviceWrapper deviceWrapper, string name, int number)
    {
        _device = deviceWrapper;
        Name = name;
        TableNumber = number;
    }

    public float P1 
    {
        get { return getVal(0); } 
        set { setVal(0, value); }
    }

    public float P2
    { 
        get { return getVal(1); }
        set { setVal(1, value); }
    }

    public float P3  // Notice that I have three numerical values 
    {
        get { return getVal(2); }
        set { setVal(2, value); }   // I typed "1" here accidentally... Bug!
    }

    public float P4
    {
        get { return getVal(3); }
        set { setVal(3, value); }
    }

    public float P5
    {
        get { return getVal(4); }
        set { setVal(4, value); }
    }

    public float P6
    { 
        get { return getVal(5); }
        set { setVal(5, value); }
    }

    public float P7
    { 
        get { return getVal(6); }
        set { setVal(6, value); }
    }

    public float P8
    { 
        get { return getVal(7); }
        set { setVal(7, value); }
    }



    private float getVal(int pos)
    {
        return _device.GetCalibrationValue(TableNumber, pos);
    }

    private void setVal(int pos, float val)
    {
        _device.SetCalibrationValue(TableNumber, pos, val);
    }



    internal void FillWithValue(float value)
    {
        P1 = value;
        P2 = value;
        P3 = value;
        P4 = value;
        P5 = value;
        P6 = value;
        P7 = value; 
        P8 = value;  // "foreach" by hand, really? :o(
    }
}
```

EDIT: XAML, with accepted answer's suggestion:

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="A1" Binding="{Binding [0]}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="B1" Binding="{Binding [1]}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="A2" Binding="{Binding [2]}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="B2" Binding="{Binding [3]}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="A3" Binding="{Binding [4]}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="B3" Binding="{Binding [5]}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="A4" Binding="{Binding [6]}" Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="B4" Binding="{Binding [7]}" Width="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Use a `List<float>`? Or maybe `ObservableCollection<float>`?

Comment: Could you include your XAML? I'll adapt my answer to work with it.

Comment: If it was me, I would use partial classes and code generation (maybe some T4) to create the properties; no manual code to write...

Comment: @MarcGravell indexed binding solved my current problem, but I'll consider this design choice (code generation) in the future!

Comment: Yes, that would work, assuming that the `DataGrid`'s `ItemsSource` is bound to a collection of `MemoryTable` instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could bind to indexed properties:

```
public float this[int i]
{
    get { return getVal(i); }
    set { setVal(i, value); }
}
```

In XAML:

```
<!-- If MemoryTable instance is property of current data context -->
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyMemoryTable[1]}" />

<!-- If MemoryTable instance itself is current data context -->
<TextBox Text="{Binding [1]}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple different ways, but I'm not particularly fond of any of them.

One would be to implement the properties as an indexer:

```
public float this[int index]
{
    get { return getVal(index); }
    set { setVal(index, value); }
}
```

You'd need to add in range checking as someone could try to do `myObject[7]` and that shouldn't be allowed. You can bind to an indexer in WPF. So that *might* work. But it does put the onus on the consumer of your class since they won't get intellisense for the properties (since its just an integral parameter).

Another option would involve some trickery with reflection to get the name of the property being set and use that to determine which value to pass into `getVal`/`setVal`. But that's got reflection and string parsing at least, which feels... wrong. But this would be akin to using the [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) or the `nameof` operator coming in C# 6.